# Laravel 5.4 Chaining to display Auth data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this in my master blade

```
<?php $user=auth()->user() ?>
{{ $user->id }}
```

Im using this code to display the ID of my user detail,
Can you suggest a way to remove `<?php ?>` or atleast a cleaner approach on this auth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `id()` method:

```
{{ auth()->id() }}
```

If you need some other property or related data to display, use `user()` to get current user object:

```
{{ auth()->user()->name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like :

```
{{ auth()->user()->id }}
```

or if you have Laravel Auth

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try above suggested answered as cleaner approach, but if you want to remove `<?php ?>`, you can try below code:

```
{{--*/ $user=auth()->user() /*--}}
```

I recommend to use above answered cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store user to variable initialize it on `@php`. For example

```
@php($user = auth()->user())
{{ $user->id }}
```